# Change html <a> letters length on resolution change?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an HTML code: `<a><span>My Text -</span> Loooong Text</a>`
Output: My Text - Loooong Text 
When screen resolution goes to width lower than 445px, I want `Loooong Text` as: `L. Text`, and if it increases, text returns to original size.

Any help? Thanks.

Comment: You can use pseudo selectors to achieve this but you have to add `id` or class to your `<a>` or `<span>`.

Comment: I have ids and classes on it, can you give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can split the text into more  elements, and then use @media query in your CSS to decide which to show and which to hide.

**HTML**:

```
<a>
    <span>My Text -</span> 
    <span id='long'>Loooong Text</span>
    <span id='short'>L. Text</span>
</a>
```

**CSS**:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 445px) {
   #short { display: inline; }
   #long { display: none; }
}
@media screen and (min-width: 446px) {
   #short { display: none; }
   #long { display: inline; }
}
```

Comment: There's a problem in doing this, text in `Loooong Text` is issued by PHP and it changes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a modification of Koby Douek's answer that might suit you.
also utilizing @media.

Wrap the collapsing portion in a span. Then use media queries to toggle its display. You can use this class to wrap anything you want to collapse.

**HTML**:

```
<a>
    <span>My Text -</span> 
    L<span class='collapse'>oooong</span> Text
</a>
```

**CSS**:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 445px) {
   .collapse { display: none; }
   .collapse::after {content: '.'}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 446px) {
   .collapse { display: inline; }
}
```

You mentioned you are generating the content using a PHP script, this strategy should be compatible.